# Compare PHP current timestamp to timestamp in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, timestamp

As the title says.

From the database, in the resultset, I want those rows where the date and time **(schedule column)** are already passed.

In the database I have
[image]

On the PHP page I have:

```
$now = time();
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM schedules WHERE $now >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(schedule)");
```

However, if I test this on 2015-09-19 at 18:50:00, I get no results at all, while instead I should only get the row with ID 39.

As much as I know I am comparing two valid timestamps - the one generated by time() and the one converted from the database with UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - so what isn't working?

EDIT: I already tried to do
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM schedules WHERE NOW() >= schedule");

But with no luck. I am getting the results with

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row['ID'];
    echo $id;
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of your `schedule` column?

Comment: It is set to timestamp. Apologizes for not writing it in the post.

Comment: And does `SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP;` give the correct UTC time?

Comment: No it doesn't but I already knew it - please check the comment under Fuzzytree's answer

Comment: Are you comparing times in the same timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `now()` to select rows where `schedule` is in the past

```
SELECT * FROM schedules WHERE now() > schedule
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just tried this but I keep getting no results. PS: I'm editing the post to show how I am trying to get the resultset.

Comment: @wiredmark what does `select now()` produce? i'm guessing the time is not what you expect it to be

Comment: @FuzzyTree: Beware, that `SELECT NOW()` will give results in the session's `time_zone`.  Better to check system time with `SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: I just noticed that NOW() gets the server current time that is of course different from mine. I already tought about it before however.. but this doesn't explains why it doesn't work if I use PHP's time(), right? In that case I was comparing my PHP's time (which is correct) with a simple timestamp in the DB

Comment: @wiredmark: `TIMESTAMP` columns are stored in UTC and converted to/from the session's `time_zone` on data retrieval/storage.  Therefore you would see erroneous results if the system clock is correctly set but MySQL is using an erroneous `system_time_zone`, which `SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP` would reveal.

Comment: That query returned me 2015-09-19 17:24:32 which is two hours earlier than my Europe/Rome time. Is this the reason why FuzzyTree's query doesn't works?

Comment: Europe/Rome (currently on CEST) is indeed UTC+2. So that actually sounds correct.  What is the session timezone: `SELECT @@session.time_zone`?

Comment: It's set to System. Since I am using Plesk I changed the server time to Europe/Rome and rebooted the mysqld service. But the SELECT_UTC timestamp query keeps giving me the wrong result. I am working on it now to understand the causes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90119/discussion-between-wiredmark-and-eggyal).

Comment: Seems like there was something wrong and I didn't really reboot the server. After setting the right server time for mysql everything worked flawlessly. Thank you for all the help. I will set this as the correct answer as it's the solution I'm using right now.

Answer (score -2):

They are different because,
php time is based on the php timezone setting (inside php.ini).
database time is based on your system time (unless you set it).

Comment: [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) returns seconds since UNIX epoch—i.e. it is in UTC/timezone independent.

Comment: This is not the case ^^

Comment: try `SELECT * FROM schedules WHERE NOW() > DATE(schedule)`

Comment: If I try that query I get all the results from the table. However I just need one row, because that is the only one time that is passed standing to the example I wrote in the post..